# Creating certificate for IIS to be used for HTTPS on the local network

Tags: iis, https, openssl, ssl-certificate, web-hosting

I'm attempting to create a certificate to be able to serve web pages over https (IIS) on the local network.
I'm trying to create a CA root certificate, an intermediate CA certificate and the a certificate for the server to use for hosting web pages on a local IIS - but I can't quite get the last bit to work, or so I think at least.

Because everything seems to work/look at expected but the browser still doesn't like the certificate used for the web server.

Here is how I'm creating the certificates (via batch script) - it's been hacked together from different samples I've found. I'm using OpenSSL 3.2.0 from FireDaemon.

```
openssl genpkey -algorithm RSA -out root-ca-key.pem
openssl req -new -x509 -key root-ca-key.pem -out root-ca-cert.pem -days 1825 -subj "/CN=sysConLocalRootCA"
openssl x509 -inform PEM -in root-ca-cert.pem -outform DER -out root-ca-cert.cer

openssl genpkey -algorithm RSA -out intermediate-ca-key.pem
openssl req -new -key intermediate-ca-key.pem -out intermediate-ca-csr.pem -subj "/CN=SysConLocalIntermediateCA"
openssl x509 -req -in intermediate-ca-csr.pem -CA root-ca-cert.pem -CAkey root-ca-key.pem -out intermediate-ca-cert.pem -days 1825 -extfile _basic_constraints.txt
openssl x509 -inform PEM -in intermediate-ca-cert.pem -outform DER -out intermediate-ca-cert.cer

openssl genpkey -algorithm RSA -out server-key.pem
openssl req -new -key server-key.pem -out server-csr.pem -subj "/CN=win-d77pp2emm6s"
openssl x509 -req -in server-csr.pem -CA intermediate-ca-cert.pem -CAkey intermediate-ca-key.pem -out server-cert.pem -days 1825
openssl pkcs12 -export -out server-cert.pfx -inkey server-key.pem -in server-cert.pem -certfile intermediate-ca-cert.pem
```

The file *_basic_constraints.txt* just contains the line "basicConstraints=CA:TRUE".

I'm installing **root-ca-cert** into the *Trusted Root Certification Authorities* store, the **intermediate-ca-cert** into *Intermediate Certification Authorities* store and finally the **server-cert** into the *Personal* store on the server.

If I inspect the certificate chain it all looks fine from what I can tell, but when I try to use the server-cert for hosting on https, the browser isn't happy about it.

The binding is made like this (picture 1):

[image]

The URL I'm attempting to open is: https://win-d77pp2emm6s.

The name of the server is "win-d77pp2emm6s".
But as you can see, the browser doesn't accept it (picture 2).

[image]

What am I missing or doing wrong here?

**UPDATE 1**

After trying to generate a report with the suggested Jexus Manager tool, the result regarding https looks like this (picture 3).
Does this mean that it's currently the lack of a SAN that is the issue? - and if so, how can I add that during certificate creation in a way that would be accepted by IIS 10?

[image]

Comment: A report can show quite a lot https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ssl-diagnostics.html

Comment: I will try this Jexus Manager then and see what it suggests. Don't know the tool.

Comment: The use of the CN for specifying the hostname has been deprecated for more than 20 years now. Use the Subject Alternative Name (SAN) field in the server certificate.

Comment: That is super odd, since all examples I ever find when I search, only mentions the CN. As stated in my update 1, I'm unsure on how to add the SAN, any good advice on that?

Comment: There are many reasons for this error, you can try to clear the cache and try again.